# Send request to JSP and receive response

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, response

I have the following scenario of integrating a third party application into my java application. The third party application is running in a different context than my java application. It provides a JSP which needs to be called with certain parameters such as authentication information based on which it generates a cookie value and sets it in the header. I need to call this JSP from my java application and then retrieve the headers from the response with the cookie value and set it to the new cookie that will be created in my application.

I was able to call the JSP using

```
response.sendRedirect("http://<host>:<port>/<context>/authn.jsp").
```

The authn.jsp was able to retrieve all values sent authenticate and generate the cookie value. It then does the

```
response.setHeader(attr,val).
```

However, I am not sure how to read this response header back in my servlet. Is request.sendRedirect the correct way to do this? Do I need to use the HTTPURLConnection class to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `HTTPURLConnection` to read the headers. You cannot use `response.sendRedirect(..)`. Once you have received the headers, you can set `response.setHeader(attr,val)` in your code.

```
URL url = new URL("JSPURL");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
for (int i = 0;; i++) {
  String headerName = conn.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
  String headerValue = conn.getHeaderField(i);
  System.out.println(headerName + "===");
  System.out.println(headerValue);
  if (headerName == null && headerValue == null) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: How is the request passed back to my servlet from the JSP using URLConnection?

Comment: `request` is always within your application or `servlet`. you're making an http connection and reading the `headers` from there and setting the headers you need in your application or servlet.

Comment: I am able to successfully open a connection to the JSP and receive the response headers. However, I am not able to retrieve the header that was set in the JSP. I am able to list other headers such as server, date, content-type and so on but not header which was set with cookie value. What am I missing here?

Comment: The only problem was i was not setting the authentication information. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 1):

If your are using Tomcat and both applications are deployed into the same server instance then you could configure both servlet applications to accept incoming requests from each other. That's done by means of the `crossContext` attribute in the [context configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Attributes).

Then, from your servlet you could use a `RequestDispatcher` against the other web application:

```
RequestDispather dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/<context>/authn.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
// Process the headers
Enumeration<String> headerNames = response.getHeaderNames();
while(headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
   Collection<String> values = response.getHeaders(headerNames.nextElement());
   // do whatever with the header values.
}
```

**NOTE**: Other servlet containers have similar ways of configuring the cross context feature, you should check your container's configuration documentation.

Comment: Both applications are deployed on the same server. I am able to  use the getRequestDispatcher and forward the request to the JSP from my servlet however once the request is passed to the JSP the response is not back to my servlet. The JSP process it and sets the header but I am not able to read it back as the request is not back to my servlet. How do I get the response back to my servlet. I cannot modify the JSP as it is delivered by a third party company.

Comment: execution flow in your servlet should continue right after the `forward` invocation unless a exception is thrown when invoking that target JSP

Comment: The target JSP is not throwing any exception. A success message is thrown at the end of the page and that is what is shown on the browser.